# In an ASP.NET application, should I buffer per-request log entries and commit infrequently?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, concurrency

I need to put a customized logging system of sorts in place for an ASP.NET application. Among other things, it has to log some data per request. I've thought of two approaches:

Approach #1: **Commit each entry per request.** For example: A log entry is created and committed to the database on every request (using a transient `DbContext`). I'm concerned that this commit puts an overhead on the serving of the request that would not scale well.

Approach #2: **Buffer entries, commit periodically.** For example: A log entry is created and added to a concurrent buffer on every request (using a shared lock). When a limit in that buffer is exceeded, an exclusive lock is acquired, the buffered entries are committed to the database in one go (using another, also transient `DbContext`, created and destroyed only for each commit) and the buffer is emptied. I'm aware that this would make the "committing" request slow, but it's acceptable. I'm also aware that closing/restarting the application could result in loss of uncommitted log entries because the AppDomain will change in that case, but this is also acceptable.

I've implemented both approaches within my requirements, I've tested them and I've strained them as much as I could in a local environment. I haven't deployed yet and thus I cannot test them in real conditions. Both seem to work equally well, but I can't draw any conclusions like this.

**Which of these two approaches is the best?** I'm concerned about performance during peaks of a couple thousand users. Are there any pitfalls I'm not aware of?

Comment: Probably depends on how verbose and frequent your logging is.

Comment: Well, a couple Thousand users is nothing to worry about. You are talking about using a DbContext and worry about bulk insert performance. Does not go together... Perhaps you should reconsider using a file to do the logging and import the file into the database afterwards

Comment: @GeorgeJohnston As far as verbosity goes, every entry is no more than 100 bytes. I'd like to know at least if thinking of taking the second approach is outrageous.

Comment: @Pleun This is the problem I'm trying to solve with approach #2. I can accept the fact that one in (say) 500 requests will inevitably be slow, because it'll be burdened with committing the 500 entries buffered by all other requests. Also, doesn't writing in a temporary log file involve writing to the disk, therefore making it worse performance-wise than buffering in memory?

Comment: I don't think that your second approach is bad at all. Finding a good ballance may be difficult, but is a good idea I think. If data loss on app restart is no problem like you say, maybe writing the log for one session on session abandon is an option. I'm using this for user settings in one of my apps. Logging should no be that much different. (But there is no really true answer I think, exept what George said)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use log4net, and set its buffer size appropriately. Then you can go home and have a beer the rest of the day... I believe it's Apache licensed, which means you're free to modify/recompile it for your own needs (fitting whatever definition of "integrated in the application, not third party" you have in mind).

Seriously though - it seems way premature to optimize out a single DB insert per request at the cost of a lot of complexity. If you're doing 10+ log calls per request, it would probably make sense to buffer per-request - but that's vastly simpler and less error prone than writing high-performance multithreaded code.

Of course, as always, the real proof is in profiling - so fire up some tests, and get  some numbers. At minimum, do a batch of straight inserts vs your buffered logger and determine what the difference is likely to be per-request so you can make a reasonable decision.

Intuitively, I don't think it'd be worth the complexity - but I have been wrong on performance before.

Answer (score 2):

To solve your concern with option 1 about slowing down each request, why not use the TPL to offload the logging to a different thread? Something like this:

```
public class Logger
{

    public static void Log(string message)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { SaveMessageToDB(message); });
    }

    private static void SaveMessageToDB(string message)
    {
        // etc.
    }

}
```

The HTTP request thread wouldn't have to wait while the entry is written. You could also adapt option 2 to do the same sort of thing to write the accumulated set of messages in a different thread.

I implemented a solution that is similar to option 2, but in addition to a number limit, there was also a time limit. If no logs entries had been entered in a certain number of seconds, the queue would be dumped to the db.

Comment: TPL was one of my first thoughts, but I don't know how thread pools behave in ASP.NET applications and I was afraid of any hidden "gotchas".